the usage about either…or…
I have several questions about the below sentence,which is from the Reading Test of IELTS(the International English Language Testing System).

But most modern humour theorists have settled on some version of Aristotle’s belief that jokes are based on a reaction to or resolution of incongruity, when the punchline is either a nonsense or, though appearing silly, has a clever second meaning.

Question1: Can I rewrite jokes are based on a reaction to or resolution of incongruity, to jokes are based on a reaction to incongruity or a resolution of incongruity,? Does the original part mean the version that I rewrote? I am almost fairly sure that the a reaction to incongruity is correct after reading the analysis about this sentence online. I am not quite sure, however, that a resolution of incongruity is right or not. I think a in the original sentence describes both reaction and resolution but I am not certain.
Question2: Does when the punchline is either a nonsense or, though appearing silly, has a clever second meaning. mean when the punchline is either a nonsense or has a clever second meaning though appearing silly.? The usage about either…or… I learned before is paralleled components must be put between them, for instance, He wants either apple juice or pear juice. He either drinks it or eats it..
I never learned this kind of sentence

He wants either apple juice or drinks pear juice.

Could anyone please help me? Thank you.

I wonder, was this a sentence in which you were meant to find or fix mistakes? The sentence is understandable and reasonable, but "a nonsense" is a rather unusual usage, and ideally "is" should come after "either" so that whichever "branch you take" the sentence is grammatical.

It's not that unusual. This is a nonsense! gets quite a few hits in Google Books. Anyway, so far as I'm concerned, It's either true or it's false is 100% valid - just because either can be placed before the first possibility (Either it's true or it's false) doesn't mean we must put it there. And I think the cited usage is syntactically identical to my true/false example - it's just nit-picking to object that the verb changed, or the subject wasn't repeated (It's either true or cannot be determined).

...which according to the OP here must be rendered Either it is true or it cannot be determined. I'm assuming the statement is in response to something like What is the value of boolean variable X at this point in program execution? OP is assuming a level of syntactic precision that simply doesn't exist in English.

@Andy Bonner Thanks. No, it is a right sentence itself and there are not any mistakes to be fixed.

@FumbleFingers Thanks. Could you please post the entire article of This is a nonsense if possible as I cannot open the link? I understand both meanings of It’s either true or it’s false. and It’s either true or cannot be determined. but I understand neither grammarlly. I vaguely felt that object that the verb changed, or the subject wasn't repeated is my knowledge blind point about my post here, probably the answer I am looking for. Could you please explain more about it because I don’t undersatnd it?

That's a link to at least a couple of dozen different published instances of the sequence "is a nonsense said" - the last word is only there to screen out false positives, but obviously it severely limits the number of matches. Trust me - it's perfectly idiomatic for many speakers to include the optional article there. Re-read my points about the position of either, possible "deletion" of a repeated subject (the punchline, in your example), and the change of verb (from is to has in your example). It's all there.

@FumbleFingers I also felt roughly that because either can be placed before the first possibility doesn't mean we must put it there. is the possible explanation I am seeking for my question here. Whereas I don’t know other rules of usage about either….or…., could you please show me its other specific rules?  The statement is from the second paragraph of IELTS Reading Passage 2 titled What’s so funny?. I will post the whole sencond paragraph below.

@FumbleFingers  Theories about humour have an ancient pedigree. Plato expressed the idea that humor is simply a delighted feeling of superiority over others. Kant and Freud felt that joke-telling relies on building up a psychic tension which is safely punctured by the ludicrousness of the punchline. But most modern humor theorists have settled on some version of Aristotle’s belief that jokes are based on a reaction to or resolution of incongruity, when the punchline is either a nonsense or, though appearing silly, has a clever second meaning.

I can't teach you any more details about this. I don't think the text you've presented should be seen as useful in terms of learning the finer points of English syntax. I'm sure it's a text specifically chosen (or created) to test your comprehension, not to teach you grammar.

We say I have questions about the sentence below (meaning 'written below').
(1) Yes, some words have been omitted to avoid repeating them. A reaction to [incongruity] or [a] resolution of incongruity.
(2) The punchline is either a nonsense or has a clever second meaning, even though it might appear silly.
Strictly speaking, to preserve the parallel structure the author should have written either is... or has...

Thanks. I learned all the either…or… sentences can be rewriten into two simple sentences. Then, in this case, it will be, when the punchline is a nonsense and when the punchline is has a clever sencond meaning. Apparently when the punchline is has a clever sencond meaning is wrong.  Based on all the knowledge I have learned before about either..or…, paralleled components MUST be put between it. Obviously, a nonsense and has a clever second meaning are not paralleled. I know the original sentence is correct but it is against my previous knowledge. HELP!

Well, to be strictly correct it should have been written "when the punchline either is nonsense or... has a clever second meaning". Certainly is has is wrong.

@KateBunting Hi! How are you doing? I upvoted your good answer!

[...] jokes are based on a reaction to or resolution of incongruity,
This is used a lot in English writing. When a noun can be followed by more than one thing [reaction to incongruity or resolution of incongruity], we skip the word and only put it at the end of the phrase.
Another example:

Their fear of or about public scrutiny as regards this topic.
fear of public scrutiny and fear about public scrutiny.

The [preceding form is an important style point for advanced students to learn.
either/or

He wants apple or pear juice. [no need for either/or there]

He will either eat the apples or drink the juice from them.


[...] when the punchline is either a nonsense or [...] has a clever second meaning. There are two possibilities.

Thanks. I know either…or… here means two possibilities. I am confused about either a response or has a clever second meaning. He wants apple or pear juice. can be rewriten into two simple sentences He wants apple juice. and He wants pear juice. He will either eat the apples or drink the juice from them. can be rewriten into two simple sentences He will eat apples. and He will drink apple juice. But if the original sentence is rewriten into two simple sentences, which will be, when the punchline is a nonsense. and when the punchline is? has? a clever…

@user510487 I answered that in the last sentence in my answer:  when the punchline is either a nonsense or [...] has a clever second meaning//to be a nonsense and to have a second meaning.

Did you mean the original sentence should be written to these two simple sentences: when the punchline is to be a nonsense and when the punchline is to have a second meaning? Where did to be and to (have) come from? Why did you put them there?

@user510487 Sorry, I've lost the thread here. The original sentence is fine.,
